# Magento2 website showing all blank pages

Tags: magento2

I am  new in magento2. I have created one new custom module. I have installed custom module. after installing website showing all pages blank.

after installing i run following commands.

```
  php bin/magento module:enable module name
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  php bin/magento cache:clean
```

when i run this command then website showing all pages blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `index.php` file to show errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function('fatal_handler');
function fatal_handler()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo ('<pre>');

    var_dump($error);
}
```

This will enable errors within magento, also check server log files

Comment: Thanks @
ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: no worries @santosh :)