# Getting all the listing page blank in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2, product-listing

I installed Magento 2.3 on my local system, but ongoing to the listing page it's showing blank. I have checked the error log, exception log, system log, debug log but nothing are there. I tried this also [Magento2 website showing all blank pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202376/magento2-website-showing-all-blank-pages) but doesn't helped me. I'm attaching a snapshot of my listing page(Gear) here for your reference.

[image].

Edit: After enabling developer mode it's giving me error like

[image]

I have overriden my catalog_category_view.xml. here is my `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!--DO NOT MODIFY :: Frontend event tracker code START-->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="shoptimize.category.tracker" template="Magento_Catalog::tracker/category-tracker.phtml">
            </block>
            <!--DO NOT MODIFY :: Frontend event tracker code START-->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: did you run indexer?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but nothing helped @sudo55

Comment: Check the product stock status and Qty as well. If the product out of stock, then it will not show on front-end.

Comment: I have almost 3500 products in my Gear category with in-stock status with qty more than 50 for every product. @DSingh

Comment: Please share the url

Comment: As I have mentioned, it is installed on my local system. so not be able to send URL @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: is gear a main category or it contain subcategory? if it contain sub category and products are assigned there, then pls enable anchor yes.

Comment: hope the footer is loading, ie footer contents are showig. your screenshot doesnt contain that.

Comment: Gear is the main category it doesn't have any subcategory and yes footer is also not loading.@ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: ok, that means its not products, your category page got some issue. is it in developer mode? if not please set it and see var/log folder/

Comment: can you take view source, there must be an error throwing.

Comment: I have enabled developer mode, but now on opening listing page, it's giving me some error as I have pasted in the edited section of my question @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: are you using any attribute integrity and croosorgin from the <link rel="stylesheet"> you have added and let me know.

Comment: you must be added this attributes somewhere, pls cross check and update me back..

Comment: did you checked?

Comment: can you share catalog_category_view.xml code here?

Comment: this can be found insde xml, you can use grep feature to fetch and identify the path to it. it can be related to module or theme.

Comment: I fixed crossorigin issue that is coming but still, my listing page is not showing@ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: what error is now showing?

Comment: it's giving no error now @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: if the footer is not loading, app/bootstrap.php, there is:
#ini_set('display_errors', 1); please uncomment that and see. the error will show.. then pls get back to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution of my own problem, actually there was a problem in product data, product data coming was invalid due to that it was not rendering phtml file of listing page. So I just added **try catch block in foreach** at `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` and it's now working fine. Here is the code after changes I have made

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php try { ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <?php
                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                if ($pos != null) {
                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                }
                ?>
                <!--DO NOT MODIFY. TRACKER DIV WRAPPER START-->
                <div data-is-trackable="true" data-tracking-context="<?php echo $tracker_constants::PRODUCT_CLICK; ?>" data-event-properties=
                '{"product_id": <?php echo $_product->getId() ?>,
                    "sku": "<?php echo $_product->getSku() ?>",
                    "product_price": <?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice() ?>,
                    "source": "Catalog Page"
                     }'>
                    <!--DO NOT MODIFY. TRACKER DIV WRAPPER TILL HERE-->
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
         <?php }
            catch (\Exception $err) {
                //echo $err->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```